# How to switch to bootstrap popups

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to switch to a popup on bootstrap modal webpage and it doesn't allow the click on a radio button. The page has only 1 frame therefore I cannot switch to another frame.

My element is:

```
input class type="radio"
"Create the account myself"
```

I'm using XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class type = 'radio' and contains(text(), 'Create the account myself')]")).click();
```

Please assist.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML for the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modal Switching**

Bootstrap modals are not iFrames, and as such, there is no need to "switch" the driver context to them. You should have no problem locating modal elements as you would any other element in the DOM.

If you want to locate elements within the modal, I have found the following approach to be useful.

```
WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath to modal container here>"));
WebElement child = modal.findElement(By.xpath("<relative xpath to child element here"));
```

Where the child xpath begins with `.//`. The leading dot indicates to "search from the current node". Since we are calling `findElement` from the context of the modal container, the search will only return matches that are children of the modal. `By.id`, `By.className`, etc. will do the same when called from the context of an element.

**XPath Issue**

The portion of your XPath `@class type = 'radio'` isn't quite right. `@type` is the attribute you should be trying to match on. `@class` appears to be empty (I would have to see the actual HTML to be sure).

**Try the following**

The final issue is that the text you are searching for actually belongs to the `<label>` element that is the direct parent of the radio button, so we first must locate the label based on the specified text, and then get the child radio element. The code below should do what you're looking for.

```
WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'modal-body')]"));
WebElement radio = modal.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@class='radiogroup-element' and contains(@style,'block') and text()='Create the account myself']/input[@type='radio']"));
radio.click();
```

As in the generic example above, it will first locate the modal. Then it will find the intended radio button from the context of the modal and click it.

Comment: You are right VanderLinden, @class is empty. The problem though is switching to the pop up

Comment: You say "the page only has 1 frame therefore I cannot switch to another frame". Why are you trying to switch to another frame? Is the element in question a child of an <iframe> element in the DOM? Just because the modal appears to "pop up" doesn't necessarily mean it is in a separate frame.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the problem you indicated with frame switching. If you are still unable to resolve the issue, you will probably need to edit your question with the relevant HTML to get more assistance.

Comment: <div class="modal-body GEHR2AJDJO" style="height: 340px;"><h6>What would you like to do?</h6><div class="row"><div class="col-md-24"><div><div><label class="radiogroup-element" style="display: block;"><input class="" type="radio">Create the account myself</label><label class="radiogroup-element"

Comment: I have just added the HTML

Comment: I have updated the answer to address the final problem. That code should work for you unless there are multiple modals present on the page. In that case, you could include the `GEHR2AJDJO` portion of the `@class` attribute to identify the specific modal. I typically try to leave out spaces when matching attribute values with XPath because I have found it can introduce flakiness.

Comment: Wow! @VanderLinden, it works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. It's a good example of one reason why relying on displayed text for element location should be avoided whenever possible. In this case there's no way around it, and the solution is somewhat tricky. If `@id='self-create-radio'` (or something similar) had been added to the radio button element, your life would have been much easier. QA and Dev teams must work together to improve testability in such situations.

Comment: Totally agree @VanderLinden, QA and Dev teams must work together to make things easier.